# Как реализовать в Java 2 метода с одинаковым названием из разных интерфейсов в одном классе?

Tags: java, интерфейс

```
public interface IGenerator {
    void on();
}

public interface IStarter {
    void on();
}

public class Bmw implements IGenerator, IStarter {

    @Override
    public void on() {
        System.out.println("Включить");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bmw bmw = new Bmw();
        bmw.on();
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** мало того, что если 2 метода с одинаковым именем будут в одном классе, тогда будет ругаться компилятор и говорить что у нас дубликат. А как реализовать в Java 2 метода с одинаковым названием из разных интерфейсов в одном классе?

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Это будет один метод в итоге. А вот как реализуешь, так он работать и будет.

Я думаю, тут просто немного недопонимания сути интерфейсов.

Интерфейс - точка взаимодействия, должен описать все необходимые методы для правильного взаимодействия двух объектов, но только на уровне, что на входе и что на выходе. Это не класс, он не имеет реализации. Потому, когда в коде встретится любой из объектов, который имеет одинаковый интерфейс, ожидается, что вызвав нужный метод, получишь нужный результат. Какой результат выполнения будет для метода класса, который реализует 2, 3 или 4 похожих интерфейса - зависит только реализации.

Answer (score 2):

Дополню предыдущего оратора. Метод `on()` будет один и будет имплементацией обоих интерфейсов сразу.

Чуть-чуть допилил ваш код для наглядности:

```
public class Test {
    public interface IGenerator {
        void on();
    }

    public interface IStarter {
        void on();
    }

    public static class Bmw implements IGenerator, IStarter {
        @Override
        public void on() {
            System.out.println("Включить");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IGenerator iGenerator = new Bmw();
        IStarter iStarter = new Bmw();

        iGenerator.on(); // Включить
        iStarter.on();   // Включить
    }
}
```

---

Всплывающая подсказка на полях в `IDEA`:

[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете реализовать эти два интерфейса в разных классах и затем использовать экземпляры этих классов в одном классе.  Так вы вызовите именно те методы, которые вам нужны.
Пример:

```
interface IGenerator {

void on();
}

interface IStarter {

void on();
}

class CGenerator implements IGenerator {

@Override
public void on() {
    System.out.println("CGenerator.on");
}
}

class CStarter implements IStarter {

@Override
public void on() {
    System.out.println("CStarter.on");
}

}

public class Bmw {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CStarter cs = new CStarter();
    CGenerator cg = new CGenerator();
    cs.on();
    cg.on();
}

}
```

Здесь у нас получилось три класса. Другой вариант использовать только два класса. И реализация интерфейсов будет в двух классах.